# Game theory: Finding the core

Tags: game-theory

$v(1234) = 4$

$v(123) = v(124) = v(134) = v(234) = 3$

$v(12) = 2$

$v(13) = v(14) = v(23) = v(24) = v(34) = 1$

$v(1) = v(2) = v(3) = v(4) = 0$

What is the core of this game?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What work have you done so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Théophile Thank you. Im unsure of how to get started on this question. The notes I have got are insufficient and I have been looking at it for a while. Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Suppose that core includes an allocation where one of the players gets more than $1$. What would happen in light of the payoffs $v(123) = v(124) = v(134) = v(234) = 3$?

Comment: I worked it out! Thanks for your help!